# generate multiple output from t4 preprocessed text templates

Tags: .net, t4

I was wondering if there is a way to generate multiple files from my preprocessed template?

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessed templates return the whole generated code as a string when you call the "TransformText()" method. It's up to you in what file(s) that result is saved.

You could render tokens into that generated code wherever you want to start a new file, split the returned string and save each part in a separate file.

For example - if this was your preprocessed template:

```
<#@ template #>

// This output text goes to the first file

NEW_FILE_TOKEN

// this output text goes to the next file
```

And your calling code would be like this:

```
var myTemplateInstance = new MyTemplate();
var result = myTemplateInstance.TransformText();

var fileContents = result.Split("NEW_FILE_TOKEN");
for(int i = 0; i < fileContents.Count; i++)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("File" + i.ToString() + ".txt", fileContents[i]);
}
```

You'd end up with two files (File0.txt, and File1.txt), one containing the first comment line and the other one the second.